# How to find count of N columns in a table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a DB2 table 'XMAS' with Columns X1,X2,X3,X4...X300.
Now, i would like to list the columns X1,X2,X3 and X4 only and their respective counts in the result. Please help me out. I am new to SQL. thanks

Comment: Give us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What does "respective count" mean?

Comment: @priyan you edited my answer instead of commenting on it !!! yes that will return colname and their count from XMAS grouping colname and count of theirs sideways!!!!

Comment: Oh i am sorry Nikhil, i am new here. Thank you so much for your response and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select colname,count(*) from XMAS group by colname ;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.